# Python Kivy Canvas wont Update

Tags: python, canvas, kivy

I am creating a 'Map editor' using 64x64 tiles. I need my canvas to update when i click and change the tile at location. I originally set the canvas with

```
with self.canvas:
    Rectangle(source = 'image.png')
```

in one class, then in my touch_down class i call

```
with self.canvas:
    Rectangle(source = 'newImage.png')
```

after i change my image to update it.

I have been able to get it to update but i have to create a new image each time, it seems it wont update since i already added that rectangle with that specific source image, and doesn't see that the image has been changed?

**In response to Ryan P**

Still nothing. I tried this

```
Class mypaintwidget(Widget): #This is added as a widget to my layout
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            self.rect = Rectangle(source = 'image.png')
        tilepng = pil.open('64x64tile.png') #pil is Python Image Library
        tilemap = pil.open('image.png')       
        tilemap.paste(tilepng,location)
        tilemap.save('newimage.png')
        self.rect.source = 'newimage.png'
```

It will only update ONCE. then nothing (but will still save that image, but wont show it to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to modify the `Rectangle` instruction (or remove and replace, but modifying is easier):

```
with self.canvas:
    self.rect = Rectangle(source='image.png')
```

Then later:

```
self.rect.source = 'newImage.png'
```

---

As for the second part of your question, the issue is that images are cached upon loading in Kivy. So when you save `newimage.png` and reload it again, Kivy knows you've already loaded `newimage.png`. This isn't really a good design for a Kivy app.

Also, creating the `Rectangle` in `on_touch_down` means you end up creating a new `Rectangle` each time the widget is pressed, so you just add more and more unnecessary drawing instructions.

You may also notice that when you add multiple of these widgets to a layout, that they all render in the same place at the full size of the window. Widgets are not constrained to drawing in their area, and can draw anywhere within the app. You need to make sure the `Rectangle` instruction knows where to draw, by passing it `size` and `pos` parameters.

Finally, instead of saving out the image, you can just display one atop the other. This will be much more efficient and doesn't require using unique filenames or messing with the caching system.

You should definitely take a look at the [Kivy language (kv)](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html) as it is much easier to use for designing widgets and laying out your app.

Here's an example of using kv to do this:

```
<TileWidget>:
    tilesource: ''

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            source: 'image.png'
        Color:
            a: 1 if self.tilesource else 0
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            source: self.tilesource
```

Now I'll explain what all of this does.

```
<TileWidget>:
```

This is a class rule, because the name is surrounded by `<>`. It will apply to all instances of `TileWidget`.

```
    tilesource: ''
```

Here we are [setting the value of the property](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html#introduction-to-properties) `tilesource`. But `tilesource` isn't a property on the `Widget` class! No worries. In kv, when you assign a value to a non-existent property like this, the property will be created automatically. Since the value we're assigning to the property is a string, Kivy will realize we want this to be a [`StringProperty`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.StringProperty).

By creating this property, we are making it possible to affect this widget from the outside. We will use the value of this property to display an image later.

```
    canvas:
```

Just like using `with self.canvas:` from the class in Python.

```
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Inside a `canvas` block, we can add drawing instructions. We start with a [`Color` instruction](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.context_instructions.html#kivy.graphics.context_instructions.Color), because you don't know what the color is currently set to. This color will tint the images we display, and we don't want any tint, so we use a full white color.

```
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            source: 'image.png'
```

Now we are going to render the first image. We make sure that the `Rectangle`'s size and pos match the widget. In kv, doing this automatically creates a binding. If the widget is moved around, its size will change, and the `Rectangle` will update itself to match.

```
        Color:
            a: 1 if self.tilesource else 0
```

This time, we know what the color is set to. However, we don't want to draw anything else until an image has been set. In kv, properties will accept any Python value. This means you can use [ternary expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator) like this one, or function calls, or arithmetic, etc. So if `self.tilesource` evaluates to False (like an empty string, the default value we set above) then the `a` property of the color (the alpha component) will be set to 0, otherwise it will be 1.

```
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            source: self.tilesource
```

Finally, we render the selected image.

Now, to create the widget itself, we just need a little bit of Python:

```
class TileWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.tilesource = '64x64tile.png'
            return True
        return super(TileWidget, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

It's important to use [`collide_point`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.collide_point) when handling touches. Just like how widgets can draw anywhere in the app, they can also handle touches anywhere in the app. This makes sure that the touch is actually within the bounds of our widget before acting. **Inside** the `collide_point` block, we will return True to let Kivy know that we have handled this touch and that nothing else should process it. Otherwise, we call [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) to let the default handler take over.

Comment: I cant seem to use 
    *self.rect.source = 'newImage.png'*
in a different class than *with self.canvas: self.rect = Rectangle(source = 'image.png')*
i get an error *AttributeError: 'class' object has no attribute 'rect'*

Comment: In that case, part of your problem was you were trying to add the second Rectangle to a different canvas. You need to reference the original widget to change the Rectangle on it.

Comment: I cant get code to show nicely in these comments im going to add it to my question

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer that in such detail.